# Selecting one node among close nodes

Tags: neo4j

Assume I have a set of nodes.

In the set, there are some group. Like this.

group1 : (A)->(B)->(C)

group2 : (D)->(E)->(F)->(G)->(H)

group3 : (I)->(J)

In this case, I want to select only one node in each group.
For example. A in group1, F in group2, J in group3

How can I do this? Please help me

Answer (score 0):

If your **groups** are collections you can reference each item in the collection individually.

This example creates three collections: group1, group2, and group3 and then returns an item from each.  The items in the collections could just as easily be nodes as strings.

```
with ['A', 'B', 'C'] as group1
, ['D','E','F','G','H'] as group2
, ['I','J'] as group3
return group1[0],group2[2], group3[1]
```

Updated answer to show matching three separate paths (group1, group2, group3) each starting with a letter in the example provided (A, D, I).

```
match group1=(:Alpha {name: 'A'})-[*1..5]->(:Alpha)
, group2=(:Alpha {name: 'D'})-[*1..5]->(:Alpha)
, group3=(:Alpha {name: 'I'} )-[*1..5]->(:Alpha)
return (nodes(group1))[0]
, (nodes(group2))[2]
, (nodes(group3))[1]
```

Comment: sorry, not following. can you elaborate?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But this is not that I wanted. I think my explanation is not enough because I'm not good at English.. The example is just an example. In example, alphabets mean nodes and these are already exists before sending a query. And arrow(->) means relationship. Then, I think have to start query something like this. MATCH (n) / WHERE NOT (n)-[*]-(n) ???? / RETURN n

Comment: I added some cypher that matches the paths of nodes you have in your example. It then references a particular node in each path.

Comment: Thank you! I admire your skill